# Find increment between cells for their sum to reach a certain amount

Tags: arrays, excel, loops, conditional-statements

```
Dim i As Double
Dim myRange
Dim results As Double

myRange = Worksheets("V1 PI by Rank Gap, LoS by Ratio").Range("U3", "U29")

Do Until results >= 1

i = Worksheets("V1 PI by Rank Gap, LoS by Ratio").Range("V3").Value

i = i + 0.000000000001

results = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)

Loop
```

hi all, I'm trying to use loop to find the "increment/gap" needed for the sum of an array of rows to reach value "1"

but the code I attempted renders Excel unresponsive....

thanks for any input

[image]

Comment: Your loop should stop when j = 1. Since you aren't changing the value of j in the loop j retains the value it had before the loop - even after a million loops. Therefore your problem isn't one of syntax but one of logic. We can help you write but we can't help you think.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. What formula/math are you trying to run? As @Variatus mentions, your `Do` loop doesn't really do anything except increment a variable.  Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: hi guys thanks for helping, I'm trying to get V3 cell to automatically increase by 0.0000001 until SUM(U3:U29)=1 (100%)

Comment: @Variatus hi sir, what about after this last edit?

Comment: `i = i + 0.0000001` should have `i` of Double data type. `Results` should probably be a Double, too since you require high precision. Observe that 2.77777777 + 0.0000001 will never become exactly 1. Therefore your test should be `=>1`. However, `Results` will be ` = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)` after every loop, uneffected by V3 or `i`. Therefore the loop can't end. Observe that `MyRange` never changes. Therefore it should be set before the loop. The loop should cause some change to its value.

Comment: @Variatus hi sir, I amended with your input... but 1 question, will excel functions in spreadsheet run concurrently with VBA macro?... U28 is actually U29 + V3 and so on...

Comment: Why don't you simply use the Excel "Solver" add-in to do this?  It's designed specifically for this kind of thing.

Comment: The worksheet functions would run concurrently unless `Calculation` is turned off. However,  your loop makes no changes to the values of U29 or V3. On each loop it reads these two values into `i` and then adds 0.0000001 to that value. Perhaps, instead of `i = i + 0.000000000001` you mean `Worksheets("V1 PI by Rank Gap, LoS by Ratio").Range("V3").Value = i + 0.000000000001`

Comment: @Frank Ball Great suggestion! However, I think the OP will need your help encoding it. Can you post an answer to that effect?